Prove the sequence $\frac{1}{2}$, $\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{2}}$, $\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{2}}}$... converges.
The recursion formula for the sequence is $a_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2+a_{n}}, n \ge 1, a_{1}=\frac{1}{2}$. The hint of the question was to prove {$a_{2n+1}$} is decreasing and bounded below, and {$a_{2n}$} is increasing and bounded above. Therefore, according to MCT, the sequence converges, but I can't prove either them are monotonic increasing or decreasing. I know that the sequences converges to $\sqrt{2}-1$ and the recursion formula for the subsequences are $a_{2(n)+[1]}=\frac{2+a_{2(n-1)+[1]}}{5+2a_{2(n-1)+[1]}}$ but I don't know how to manipulate it rigorously as the fractional part is complicated.

Root2-1????????

This is Continued fraction theory. The given Continued fraction is $\sqrt{2}-1$. The Convergents have the necessary Property you want.

See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/566064/42969 or https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3406377/42969 or https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1134313/42969 or https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2729836/42969 – all found with Approach0

Yes, this is a property of contInued fractions, you can simply show it by assuming $\lim n to \inf a_{n}=l$, therefore its subsequence {$a_{n+1}$}$_{k=1}^\inf$ also converges to $l$ therefore $l=\frac{l}{2+l}, l=\sqrt(2)-1$

@DoRealAnalysis: $\lim_{n \to \infty}$ yields $\lim_{n \to \infty}$, if you're unaware.

There are many ways to analyze the sequence in the OP. Are I just present a general result regarding convergence of continued fractions with positive terms:
For any sequences of positive numbers $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ defined   the maps
\begin{align}
M_n(x)&=\tfrac{a_1}{b_1+\tfrac{a_2}{b_2+\ddots \begin{matrix}
  \\
  +\tfrac{a_{n-1}}{b_{n-1}+\tfrac{a_n}{b_n+x}}
\end{matrix}}}\\
&= \frac{p_{n-1}x+p_n}{q_{n-1}x+q_n}
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
p_n&=a_np_{n-2}+ b_np_{n-1},\qquad p_0=0,\, p_1=a_1\\
q_n&=a_nq_{n-2}+b_nq_{n-1},\qquad q_0=1,\, q_1=b_1
\end{align}
The terms $M_n(0)$ are known as convergents of the continued fraction
$$\tfrac{a_1}{b_1+\tfrac{a_2}{b_2+\ddots \begin{matrix}
  \\
  +\tfrac{a_{n-1}}{b_{n-1}+\ddots}
\end{matrix}}}$$
It is easy to check that
$$M_n(x)=M_{n-1}\Big(\frac{a_n}{b_n+x}\Big)$$
The following result  gives sufficient conditions for convergence of the convergents $M_n(0)=\frac{p_n}{q_n}$.

Lemma: If $\liminf_n\frac{b_{n-1}b_n}{a_n}>0$, then $\frac{p_n}{q_n}$ converges.

A proof of this result (with limit instead of $\liminf$) can be found in the classic high school textbook Hall, H.S. and Knight, S. R., Higher algebra, 4th edition, 1889. pp. 362.

OP's sequence: In the OP, $b_n=2$ and $a_n=1$ for all $n$. Convergence of the sequence in the OP follows.
Once we know that the sequence converges, then estimating the limit in the OP's case is simple since
$x_n=\frac{p_n}{q_n}$ satisfies
$$x_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2+x_n}$$
Taking limits on both sides yields
$$x=\frac{1}{2+x}$$
or equivalently
$$x^2+2x-1=0$$
The only positive solution here is
$$x=\frac{-2+\sqrt{8}}{2}=-1+\sqrt{2}$$

Some explanations:
By induction, it can be shown that
$$\begin{align}
p_{n-1}q_n-q_{n-1}p_n=(-1)^na_1\cdot\ldots \cdot a_n\tag{0}\label{zero}
\end{align}$$
Hence
$$\begin{align}
\frac{p_{n-1}}{q_{n-1}}-\frac{p_n}{q_n}=(-1)^n\frac{a_1\cdot\ldots\cdot a_n}{q_{n-1}q_n}\tag{1}\label{one}
\end{align}
$$
and
$$\begin{align}
\frac{p_n}{q_n}-\frac{p_{n-2}}{q_{n-2}}=(-1)^{n-1}b_n\frac{a_1\cdot\ldots\cdot a_{n-1}}{q_nq_{n-2}}\tag{2}\label{two}
\end{align}$$
More generally
$$\begin{align}
M_n(x)-M_n(y)=(-1)^n(x-y)\frac{a_1\cdot\ldots\cdot a_n}{\big(q_{n-1}x+q_n\big)\big(q_{n-1}y+q_n\big)}\tag{3}\label{three}
\end{align}$$
Identities \eqref{one} and \eqref{two} imply that
$$\frac{p_{2n}}{q_{2n}}<\frac{p_{2n+2}}{q_{2n+2}}<\frac{p_{2m+1}}{q_{2m+1}}<\frac{p_{2m-1}}{q_{2m-1}}$$
for all $m, n$. Thus,  there are numbers $0<\alpha\leq \beta$ such that $p_{2n}/q_{2n}\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow \infty}\alpha$ and $p_{2n+1}/q_{2n+1}\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}\beta$.
Under the conditions of the Lemma
$$\frac{p_n}{q_n}-\frac{p_{n-1}}{q_{n-1}}=-\frac{a_nq_{n-2}}{q_n}\Big(\frac{p_{n-1}}{q_{n-1}}-\frac{p_{n-2}}{q_{n-2}}\Big)$$
Then
$$
\frac{a_nq_{n-2}}{q_n}=\frac{a_nq_{n-2}}{a_nq_{n-2} + b_nq_{n-1}}=\frac{1}{1+\frac{b_nq_{n-1}}{a_nq_{n-2}}}
$$
and further
$$\frac{b_nq_{n-1}}{a_nq_{n-2}} = \frac{b_n(a_{n-1}q_{n-3}+b_{n-1}q_{n-2})}{a_nq_{n-2}}=\frac{b_na_{n-1}q_{n-3}}{a_nq_{n-2}}+\frac{b_nb_{n-1}}{a_n}
$$
As the term $\frac{b_na_{n-1}q_{n-3}}{a_nq_{n-2}}>0$ for all $n$,  the assumption in the Lemma implies that for some $c>0$
$$0<\frac{a_nq_{n-2}}{q_n}<\frac{1}{1+c}$$
for all $n$ large enough. From this, it follows that the difference $\Big|\frac{p_n}{q_n}-\frac{p_{n-1}}{q_{n-1}}\Big|\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$, that is $\alpha=\beta$.

@J.W.Tanner: I just made an edit an corrected the term. Thanks!

We can prove the convergence by finding the closed-form formula of $a_n$ and here is the technique: define the sequence $(b_n)_n$ such that $\cases{a_n = \frac{b_n}{b_{n+1}}\\
b_1 =1}$, then:
$$\begin{align}
a_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2+a_n} &\iff \frac{b_{n+1}}{b_{n+2}} =\frac{1}{2+\frac{b_{n}}{b_{n+1}}} = \frac{b_{n+1}}{2b_{n+1}+b_n} \\
&\implies  \color{red}{b_{n+2} = 2b_{n+1}+b_n} \tag{1}
\end{align}$$
From $(1)$ and with $b_1 = 1$ and $b_2 =\frac{b_1}{a_1} = 2$, it's easy to get the closed-form formula of $(b_n)_n$:
$$b_n = \frac{(1+\sqrt{2})^{n} - (1-\sqrt{2})^{n}}{2\sqrt{2}}$$
Then
$$\color{red}{a_n = \frac{b_n}{b_{n+1}}= \frac{(1+\sqrt{2})^{n} - (1-\sqrt{2})^{n}}{(1+\sqrt{2})^{n+1} - (1-\sqrt{2})^{n+1}}}$$
We notice that $|1-\sqrt{2}|<1$ then $|1-\sqrt{2}|^n \xrightarrow{n\to +\infty} 0$ , then
$$\color{red}{a_n \xrightarrow{n\to +\infty}  \frac{1}{1+\sqrt{2}}  = \sqrt{2}-1}$$

Here is a direct approach to your problem, not depending on the theory of continued fractions, and following the method you were asked to follow. (I use similar problems when I teach convergence).
I agree that your last formula is not useful. The formula you want to use instead is
$$a_{n+2} = \frac{1}{2 + \frac{1}{2 + a_n}}
$$
Since the odd and the even subsequences have different behavior, I suggest that you study those subsequences separately:
$$a_{2k+1} = \frac{1}{2 + \frac{1}{2 + a_{2k-1}}} \qquad a_{2k} = \frac{1}{2 + \frac{1}{2 + a_{2k-2}}}
$$
I assume from your post that you already know how to prove the statement that if your sequence converges then its limit must be $\sqrt{2}-1$ (but if you don't actually know how to do that, I can add a simple proof). You can use that knowledge with good effect:

Prove by induction that $a_{2k-1} > a_{2k+1} > \sqrt{2}-1$, starting by verifying the basis step $a_1 > a_3 > \sqrt{2}-1$. Once you're done, you can use the MCT theorem to conclude that the odd subsequence converges. And knowing that it converges, you can prove that its limit must be $\sqrt{2}-1$.
Proceed similarly with the even subsequence: prove by induction that $a_{2k} < a_{2k+2} < \sqrt{2}-1$, starting by checking the basis step $a_2 < a_4 < \sqrt{2}-1$. Conclude using the MCT that the even subsequence converges. Knowing that it converges, prove that its limit must be $\sqrt{2}-1$.


I think I can conclude it as :
Considering the two subsequences {$a_{2(n)-1}$} and {$a_{2(n)}$} $n \in \mathbb{R}$, such that {$a_{2(n)-1}$}$\cup${$a_{2(n)}$}={$a_{n}$}. $a_{2(1)-1}=\frac{1}{2}\gt\sqrt{2}-1$ and $a_{2(1)}=\frac{2}{5}\lt\sqrt{2}-1$. Suppose $a_{2(n)-1}\ge\sqrt{2}-1\ge a_{2(n)}$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then $a_{2(n+1)-1}=\frac{2+a_{2(n)-1}}{5+2a_{2(n)-1}}\ge\frac{\sqrt{2}+1}{2\sqrt{2}+3}=\sqrt{2}-1,  a_{2(n+1)}=\frac{2+a_{2(n)}}{5+2a_{2(n)}}\le\frac{\sqrt{2}+1}{2\sqrt{2}+3}=\sqrt{2}-1$. Induction shows $\forall n \in\mathbb{N}$, {$a_{2(n)-1}$} is bounded below and {$a_{2(n)}$} is bounded above. Now, $a_{2(n+1)-1}-a_{2(n)-1}=\frac{-2a_{2(n)-1}^2-4a_{2(n)-1}+2}{5+2a_{2(n)-1}}=\frac{-(a_{2(n)-1}-(\sqrt{2}-1))(a_{2(n)-1}-(-\sqrt{2}-1))}{5+2a_{2(n)-1}}\lt0$, because $\frac{1}{2}\ge a_{2(n)-1}\ge\sqrt{2}-1$ , therefore {$a_{2(n)-1}$} is monotone decreasing. Similarly, $a_{2(n+1)}-a_{2(n)}=\frac{-2a_{2(n)}^2-4a_{2(n)}+2}{5+2a_{2(n)}}=\frac{-(a_{2(n)}-(\sqrt{2}-1))(a_{2(n)}-(-\sqrt{2}-1))}{5+2a_{2(n)}}\gt0$, because $\frac{2}{5}\le a_{2(n)}\le\sqrt{2}-1$, therefore {$a_{2(n)}$} is monotone increasing. According to MCT, they are both convergent which may deduce that {$a_{n}$} is a convergence sequence.
